# Spring integration synchronize multiple files

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I sync a directory with several files from a Windows server via Samba. I synchronize once per day. This is done with `Pollers.cron(..)`. However only one file is synchronized each time the poller runs. I want to synchronize all files so I added `.maxMessagesPerPoll(..)`. Is this the correct way to sync all files in the directory?

Also I would like to know if the application can do a poll when application starts in addition to the cron once per day call, if possible?

This is the code

```
public IntegrationFlow fileSync() {
  return IntegrationFlow
    .from(Smb.inboundAdapter(smbSessionFactory())
      .remoteDirectory(remoteDirectory)
      .regexFilter(regexFilter)
      .localDirectory(new File(localDirectory)),
      e -> e.id("smbInboundAdapter")
      .autoStartup(true)
    .poller(Pollers
      .cron(cronExpression)
      .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll))
  )
  .handle(message -> {
    var file = (File) message.getPayload();
    // do something with the file
  })
  .get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's correct: the default sensible behavior for Inbound Channel Adapter is to produce a single message per poll. See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-adapter-namespace-inbound

> However, in the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`, it is a bit different. The default value for `max-messages-per-poll` is `1`, unless you explicitly set it to a negative value (such as `-1`).

There is no way to start polling immediately with a `CronTrigger`. You may look into a custom `Trigger` impl where you would return `Instant.now()` for a first call and delegate to the `CronTrigger` for all subsequent polling cycles.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an example on how to implement and configure such a trigger? I created CustomCronTrigger by extending `CronTrigger` and returned `instant.now()` `if instant == null`, and else `super.nextExcution(triggerContext)`. Is this something near what you recommended? Also I cannot figure out how  I am supposed to use this class from here.

Comment: I didn't think about details of such a trigger implementation, but what you say sounds reasonable. Now, since you have that trigger, you can use it in your `poller()` configuration via `Pollers.trigger()` factory.